# Where can I find data stored with transients?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to extract some information of WordPress plugin. All plugin data information is coming from TRANSIENTS, as I read all the code.

This is the first time that I am working using WordPress. I read and understood what are transients, but I am not sure how can I read and extract information cached in transients? Is this possible? I've tried to read table wp_options without success.

I know that maybe I can use other options to extract that information, but in the moment, if I can just extract that information it will solve all my problem and I won't need to do any changes to the wordpress plugin.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation yet? WordPress has functions for this, you know.

Comment: You can see your transients with WP-CLI. Try `wp transient list`

Answer (score 1):

to read out:

```
$transient=get_transient( $name );
```

to write to:

```
set_transient($name, $value, $expiration_in_seconds);
```

i like to use the [Transients Manager](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/) for good overview of current transients.